# Como Expirar cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

Eae galera,
  É o seguinte  criei um sistema de login que usa cookie para lembrar a senha do usuário até ai tudo bem tudo funciona normal, o problema é na hora de inspirar esses cookies, no painel do meu site tem um botão sair que nada mais é que um pequeno formulário que quando clicado envia via post uma requisição para a mesma pagina da qual tem uma condição dizendo se o metodo post sair existir então expire o cookie usuario e senha, ai que esta o problema os cookies não expiram de forma alguma já tentei todos os metodos possíveis que achei na internet como esses.

```
setcookie("usuario"," ",time()-10);
setcookie("usuario","",time()-10);
setcookie("usuario",NULL);
setcookie("usuario");
```

Nenhum desses métodos funcionaram alguém saberia se necessita de algo mais ?

Comment: deveria funcionar

Comment: E como você criou esse cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Penso que isto vai solucionar o problema:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['usuario'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['usuario']);
    setcookie('usuario', null, -1, '/');
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Vlw cara, descobri qual era o meu problema, eu estava expirando o cookie em um outro diretório pelo que percebi ele deve ser expirado no mesmo diretório em que foi criado, fica a dica caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema